# Can't get all email headers with .getAllHeaders() method

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have a problem in getting all headers from email. In particular I can't get email header "**return-path:**". While I can get this header from **external mails** I can not get it from **internal mails**.

Protocol I use: IMAP4
Mail server: exchange 2010

If I open email headers for internal email on the exchange server itself I am able to see all headers:

```
Received: from VDLG-EXCH-01 with Microsoft SMTP Server
Received: from VDLG-EXCH-01
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: my@email.com
To: demo <demo@email.com>
Subject: FW: qqqq
Thread-Topic: qqqq
Thread-Index: AdOOCZ2g1WQYWPdLTH/Y8hua
Date: Tue, 16 Jan 2018 17:17:45 +0300
Message-ID: <931CD66D7759036FA@vdlg-exch-01.email.com>
References: <AD03856E3028A600@VDMS-EXCH-01.email.com>
In-Reply-To: <AA8D03856E3028A600@VDMS-EXCH-01.email.com>
Accept-Language: en-US, ru-RU
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <B36C4F75B55C516EC46FA@vdlg-exch-01.email.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: vdlg-exch-01.email.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
X-Originating-IP: [187.30.155.37]
Return-Path: my@email.com
```

However, whenever I try to get "Return-path:" via

```
 javax.mail.Message msgTemplate = source.getMessage(1);
 Enumeration<Header> header = msgTemplate.getAllHeaders();
```

I have missing Return-Path:

```
Received: from VDLG-EXCH-01 with Microsoft SMTP Server
Received: from VDLG-EXCH-01
From: my@email.com
To: demo <demo@email.com>
Subject: FW: qqqq
Thread-Topic: qqqq
Thread-Index: AdOOCZ2g1WQYWPdLTH/Y8hua
Date: Tue, 16 Jan 2018 17:33:05 +0300
Message-ID: <931CD66D7759036FA@vdlg-exch-01.email.com>
References: <AD03856E3028A600@VDMS-EXCH-01.email.com>
In-Reply-To: <AA8D03856E3028A600@VDMS-EXCH-01.email.com>
Accept-Language: en-US, ru-RU
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: vdlg-exch-01.email.com
X-MS-Has-Attach: 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong.  The Return-Path header is added when a message is received from outside the mail server.  If the message never leaves the mail server, it may not be adding the Return-Path header.

Comment: But on mail server itself there is such header. Why i can see it on the server but can't see it in the downloaded email? If I download email via Outlook the header will be present too.

Comment: If the header exists, Exchange isn't making it available using the IMAP protocol.  Turn on [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) and you can see exactly what the server is returning.  Outlook is probably configured to use the Microsoft proprietary protocol.  You might want to report this bug to Microsoft, although Exchange 2010 is a pretty old version; possibly it's fixed in a newer version.